# curl_exec return null with google cloud messaging

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

```
function sendMessageToPhone($collapseKey, $messageText, $username)
 {
   include_once 'users.php';
   $user = new users();
   $data = $user->getUser($username); 

   $apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY';

   $userIdentificador = $data["gcmcode"];

   $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Authorization:key=' . $apiKey);

   $info = array('message' => $messageText);

   $data = array(
     'registration_ids' => $userIdentificador,
     'collapse_key' => $collapseKey,
     'data' => $info);

   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

   curl_close($ch);
   return $response;    //Return null???

 }
```

The line:

```
$responde = curl_exec($ch);
```

returns null. Why? In my Android code:

```
JSONObject jdata = PostServer.getserverdata(nameValuePairs, Server.getIPServer());
```

`jdata` is null and the message isn't sent. I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to tell what's wrong, you should at least throw the error from `curl` execution:

```
$response= curl_exec($ch);
if ($response=== FALSE) {
  die('error curl: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
```

then it would make more sense to return the http code itself and find out its value:

```
return $httpCode;
```